# Update database (SQLiteDatabase issue)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

everyone. This is a piece of code from [using sqlite in android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) tutorial:

```
return db.update(employeeTable, cv, colID+"=?", 
new String []{String.valueOf(emp.getID())});
```

I don't understand why in `colID+"=?"` after '=' stay '?'

Anyone can explain this, please?

**Thanks for everyone!**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Prepared Satatement. In this case, you can define a query as a template and left some parameters to fill dynamically. You represent the parameter with an `?`.
In your case, you are indicating that `String.valueOf(emp.getID())` will substitute the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

This is parametrized statement, this mean that this `String.valueOf(emp.getID())` will be added intead of `?` character. `?` represents one argument and `String[]` represents data which will be added to `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` is where your argument is substituted into the query. Your argument in this case is `String.valueOf(emp.getID()`.